# Match string after first 'x' # number of characters

Tags: regex

I am using regex in a Google script to normalize company names, and while I am getting very close to perfect with a combination of replacing certain words, punctuation, and spaces, my last step was to replace any 3 or fewer letter words (not digits).

But that gets rid of a few companies with acronyms at the start of their name, ie AB Holding Company. I don't want this to match AB, I want it to find the rare "The", or company code (particularly foreign ones like SPA and NV along with Co and Inc). These codes are not necessarily at the end of the string, but they seem to always be at least 4 characters after the beginning.

I am currently using

```
text = text.replace(/\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)/i," ");
```

*Ignore the [a-z] as missing caps, I've dealt with that separately*

What I think would work is to "skip over" the first few characters, probably 4 to be safe, and maybe learn how to include spaces and/or digits in there for the future. So I wrote this after seeing 1 other related question here.

```
text = text.replace(/((.{4})(.*)\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)/i," ");
```

Scipts does not seem to allow a lookbehind, and my version doesn't seem to work. I'm lost.

I appreciate your help.

EDITS FOR CLARIFICATION

Comment: Can you put some sample data and your expected match or output?

Comment: The computer doesn't know the difference between acronyms and normal words, spescially since you have "dealt" with caps. It doesn't know `"ab"` compared to `"the"`, other than the length. Unless you can be certain that all acronyms are fully capitalized, then capture words as `[A-Z][a-z]*`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to match the end of string with "$" ?

so it looks like

```
text = text.replace(/\b[a-z]{1,3}\b$)/i," ");
```

this would avoid matching any word after an acronym

Comment: I think I didn't phrase my question correctly. I actually want to keep company acronyms, and I was planning to use a replace to capture any word that isn't the 2 or 3 letter company name and replace them with "". I want to get rid of "the", and company codes (like Inc, co, NA, etc...)

Comment: Wanted to clarify that those codes are not necessarily the last 3 characters of a string. They often are, but sometimes you'll find companies called "ABC Holdings Co Ltd". In this scenario I would want the regex to remove "Co" and "Ltd", but not "ABC"